# How to do migrations with EF Core 2.2 using Spatial Data?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to do migrations in Entity Framework Core 2.2 but I get some strange errors.It [should work](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2/) since the documentation does not say anything about mapping code or so.

This command:

*dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate*

results in this error:

*The property 'Point.Boundary' is of an interface type ('IGeometry'). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the NotMappedAttribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.*

I do not understand it. I have an enity, a context and all the required dependencies, including EF Core 2.2 . How do I solve it?

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NetTopologySuite" Version="1.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.0.2105168" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Model File

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Point Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context File

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class ItemContext : DbContext
    {
        public ItemContext(DbContextOptions<ItemContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Context created");
        }

        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnModelCreating");
        }
    }
}
```

The console:
[image]

Comment: which db are you using? can you post the db config part of your startup class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the link you shared is a blog that only introduces the new features. At the end of every topic, you would find a [link to the entire documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial). It seems like this suite requires an additional library based on which database you are using.

According to this documentation, you need to add the respective **Spatial NuGet Package** based on what your database is. (check the **install** section. For instance, add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite` package if you are using SQL server. Once this is done, in your startup class, within your `AddDbContext` function, you can use something like this `config.UseSqlServer("", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())`.